# WD MyCloud shares only works when internet connection is available

Tags: shared-folders, smb

I have WD MyCloud (4TB Single HDD), the problem is simply when I am disconnected from the internet I CAN NOT access my shared files through local LAN; only when the internet is available then I can see my shares. I find this ridiculous as we have internet cut-offs quite often in my area. I searched the internet and found this link: https://community.wd.com/t/smb-protocol-only-works-when-internet-connection-is-available/142759/7 , it looks like WD are forcing users to connect to the internet to use their devices.
Does any body have a clue how to use MyCloud on local LAN without an internet connection?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://superuser.com/questions/1359271/how-can-nas-work-if-it-is-not-connected-to-internet

Comment: [Can i transfer data "without" internet with my clod? - My Cloud - WD Community](https://community.wd.com/t/can-i-transfer-data-without-internet-with-my-clod/170310)

Comment: These articles did not help me resolve my issue. I still have to connect WD MyCloud to the internet to be able to access my shares in a LAN. If the internet disconnects, the WD MyClouds denies me access to the shared folders, even though I can ping and access the web dashboard of MyCloud.